# How to redirect to login page/ or making user login successful after confirm email in devise token auth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, devise-confirmable, devise-token-auth

I am using devise token auth with React frontend and now I am making user confirmable through email. Email is being sent but somehow it generates a wrong URL.

The URL that is generated is.

`http://localhost:3001/auth/confirmation.4?confirmation_token=AoWH2yYxuHHnBzJRF746`

My routes.

```
new_user_confirmation GET      /auth/confirmation/new(.:format)                                                         users/confirmations#new
                    user_confirmation GET      /auth/confirmation(.:format)                                                             users/confirmations#show
                                      POST     /auth/confirmation(.:format)                                                             users/confirmations#create
```

My app/views/devise/mailer/confirmation_instructions.html.erb

```
<p>Welcome <%= @email %>!</p>

<p>You can confirm your account email through the link below:</p>

<p><%= link_to 'Confirm my account', user_confirmation_url(confirmation_token: @token) %></p>
```

After clicking confirm my account, it takes me to my application successfully, but with the wrong URL. I will be happy if I achieve one of the following.

1. User is automatically logged in after confirming.
2. It goes to login page after confirm account and after that he gives thee credentials and login.

For 1, I have overridden the confirmations_controller.rb like.

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

class Users::ConfirmationsController < Devise::ConfirmationsController
  # The path used after confirmation.
   def after_confirmation_path_for(resource_name, resource)
     sign_in(resource) # In case you want to sign in the user
     root_path
   end
end
```

In routes.rb

```
mount_devise_token_auth_for 'User', at: 'auth', controllers: { confirmations: 'users/confirmations' }
```

Answer (score 0):

First, the url helper that you use in the email doesn't need to receive the `@resource` - this is why it generates the url with the `.4`. It should rather be

```
<p><%= link_to 'Confirm my account', user_confirmation_url(confirmation_token: @token) %></p
```

Second, according to this tutorial, you can redirect the user after confirmation, like you tried already. 
https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/wiki/How-To:-Add-:confirmable-to-Users#redirecting-user

Just give a path in your app after you signed in the user

```
def after_confirmation_path_for(resource_name, resource)
  sign_in(resource) # In case you want to sign in the user
  your_new_after_confirmation_path
end
```

So no need to go to session_new again after signing in.

Comment: Thanks for helping. I have actually updated my question with your answer. It doesn't work. Actually it doesn't even got to confirmations controller. I have tried with byebug. I don't understand why.

Comment: Not even signing in.

Comment: And when testing with byebug, did you arrive in the right controller at least? They're using a different route in the tutorial `devise_for :users, controllers: { confirmations: 'confirmations' }`

Comment: In my case it's `mount_devise_token_auth_for 'User', at: 'auth', controllers: { confirmations: 'users/confirmations' }` but it doesn't even stops in byebug. Don't understand why.

Comment: It means youre not even arriving in the controller.
Change the route to this: `devise_for :users, controllers: { confirmations: 'users/confirmations' }`

Comment: I am actually using devise_token_auth.